# How to test LDAP security configuration in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

How can I write a test for an `ldap` security configuration in `spring-boot`?

The authentication manager validates first that the user initials are present in ldap, and that the found user is `memberOf` any group set for the user filter.

Question: How could I mock the ldap response at all? Eg I want to return a user with `memberOf=CN=Team-INVALID` that should not be authentication in the scope of a test.
And I want to return a user that matches the `userSearchFilter` of course.

But which class do I have to mock for this test?

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class LdapSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("(&(initials={0})(|" +
                    "(memberOf=CN=TEAM-1,OU=Intern,DC=my-company)" +
                    "(memberOf=CN=TEAM-2,OU=Intern,DC=my-company)" +
                    "))")
            .contextSource()
            .url(ldapUrl + ldapBase)
            .managerDn(ldapUsername)
            .managerPassword(ldapPassword);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to test something spring most likely already has tested? if you want to test that your configuration works, you test the ldapauthentication flow. I have no idea how a user authenticates in your application since you have not provided that code

Comment: I'd simply like to test my custom `userSearchFilter()`. Not the ldap spring in general. So how could I test it if not mocking the real ldap server response?

Comment: maybe try using a https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-ldap-embedded and then test your authentication flow. if user can authenticate, then your search filter works, if he cant authenticate, then it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, that cannot be a solution. Imagine you'd want to test a workflow that uses a database result. And instead of mocking the sql result, you add an inmemory db instead. That's one step too far...

Comment: that is not one step to far, absolutely not. The only one that can definitely answer if your query works is a correct implementation of an LDAP. If you mock, you are basically estimating, if you mock wrong and your test passes, your test gives you a false positive which is even more dangerous. an LDAP implementation wont lie, especially if you use the same LDIFs that are used in production, in your tests. You want to unit test an LDAP integration. Unit tests are for units. Integration tests are for integrations.

Comment: dont chase test coverage, tests are there to make you sleep better at night, and to make sure things actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an embedded LDAP server with an LDIF file for your tests, like this:

```java
spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:test-server.ldif
spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=springframework,dc=org
spring.ldap.embedded.port=8389
```

And in your tests you can try to authenticate that specific user like you would do in a normal flow:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:test-server.ldif",
        "spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=${spring.ldap.base}",
        "spring.ldap.embedded.port=8389",
        "spring.ldap.embedded.url=ldap://localhost:8389/",
        "spring.ldap.embedded.credential.username=uid=admin",
        "spring.ldap.embedded.credential.password=secret",
        "spring.ldap.embedded.validation.enabled=false",
        "spring.ldap.urls=ldap://localhost:8389/",
        "spring.ldap.username=uid=admin",
        "spring.ldap.password=secret"})
public class AuthenticatingLdapApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void loginWithValidUserThenAuthenticated() throws Exception {
        FormLoginRequestBuilder login = formLogin()
            .user("user")
            .password("userpassword");

        mockMvc.perform(login)
            .andExpect(authenticated().withUsername("user"));
    }

    @Test
    public void loginWithInvalidUserThenUnauthenticated() throws Exception {
        FormLoginRequestBuilder login = formLogin()
            .user("invalid")
            .password("invalidpassword");

        mockMvc.perform(login)
            .andExpect(unauthenticated());
    }
}
```

I found this example in the [Authenticating with LDAP Guide](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-authenticating-ldap). You can refer to it for more details

Required dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
    <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How can I force replace the existing ldap from `application.properties` with the embedded one for test?

Comment: In you test folder you can create an `application.properties` file or even an `application-test.properties` and run your tests with `@ActiveaProfiles("test")`

Comment: I had to add `unboundid-ldapsdk` library for this to work. Further, I had to configure the `spring.ldap.embedded.*`, and then route my main `spring.ldap.*` properties to the embedded connection. Will update your example with the required test properties arrordingly.